# JIRA: Associating a project with a team

Tags: jira

I'm wondering how to assign users to a project in JIRA. I took over a project that was set up by someone else and notice that all the assignees are people from a different team. How do I add my team?

Bit of a brand newbie question here. Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

A JIRA project has a permission scheme. That scheme has a Assignable User permission. Make sure the list of users you want to be assignable matches what is defined there.